# how to display a fraction read from a file in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to read from an output file and write to an input file, but my program isn't working quite well. I have no idea how to fix it. I have this:

```
int i;
FILE *file;
char filename[500];
printf("Please enter the name of the file you would like to write to\n", &filename);
scanf("%s", filename);
file = fopen(filename, "w");
printf("Writing to file %s\n", filename);
fprintf("%d / %d", *num, *denom);
fclose(file);`
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong for this write file of the code?

Comment: The  correct way to use `fprintf` is: `int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
fprintf("%d / %d", *num, *denom);
```

to

```
fprintf(file, "%d / %d", *num, *denom);
```